# Need Time Tracking/Billing software that meets specific use scenario

Tags: windows, time-management

I’m trying to find a time-tracking program that will meet our needs as a company. We're an IT consulting firm and have different contracts with each client, each of which includes an allotted amount of time during which we can do work on site before we start billing overages.

(For example, “Company A” gets 4 hours per month; if they go over that we charge $100/hr for each additional hour.)

Is there any program out there that can do this type of time/billing tracking (where the first x hours are ‘free’ and additional hours greater than x are billed) automatically (E.G. we log our hours, and if it goes over x it automatically starts charging after that)?

I've tried tools like Freshbooks but that isn't automated enough for my boss.

Mobile/web app integration (iOS/Android) a plus but not required. Preferably open-source or fairly cheap (We're a 3-man shop and can't afford $150/month).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is Tele-Support HelpDesk from [Resource Dynamics](http://www.resource-dynamics.com/helpdesk.asp).  It has contract tracking that can be attached to each customer which can be set up in multiple ways allowing you to mix-and-match between support minutes, or date ranges.  There is a free demo so it costs nothing to give it a try, and the cost is fairly low.  If I remember correctly, the contracts can be set up by # of incidents, a date range (like a free support for 30 days kind of contract), or number of minutes.  I'm pretty sure there is also an export to Quickbooks.

Here is a [video](http://www.helpdesksupportline.com/video/TimeMaterialBilling.html) from their website that shows the advanced contract tracking options for time and materials.