# Online Helpdesk/Ticketing Systems

Tags: web-apps, help-desk

We are a starting company that just launched a product. We currently are not using an helpdesk ticketing system, we just answer mails.

We are looking for a system that provides:

Automatic mailing
Search of older tickets
Status
Customer accounts -> this is not required just nice to have

Kind regards

**Edit 1:**
Currently looking at:

- Solman
- Jira
- Zendesk
- Freshdesk

Comment: Depending what sort of sales approach you have, you could use SalesForce for dealing with marketing, sales leads/opportunities, and support cases. From personal experience, the product is good for support as well as the other areas, although SF standard support for their own product is not great if you have any issues which you cannot resolve for yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this seems to be a frequent question already here, you might wish to take a look at the others: [Help Desk Software?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1613/185) / [Need Time Tracking/Billing software that meets specific use scenario](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2326/185) / [other questions with the term `ticketing`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=ticketing+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Jitbit Helpdesk Ticketing system](https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/)? I'm one of the developers so I'm not going to post any review/pros/cons since I'm obviously biased.

Has all the features you mentioned and available as both online and "on-premise" solution (aka "installed on your own server").

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [HappyFox](https://www.happyfox.com/) ?

**Ticketing Features include:**

1. Convert customer emails to tickets
2. Categorize tickets based on status, priority and Agent
3. Smart Automated Workflow management
4. Manage SLAs
5. Advanced Reporting and Analytics

**The advanced ticket search feature that you were asking for.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have used [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) and [Alexsys Team](http://www.alexcorp.com/) for ticketing and happy with both products have their strengths and weaknesses and use them for internal vs. external projects. Had we know about JIRA though in the beginning I personally would have voted for JIRA now using them both for years.

I love the customizability of both, and they both have web interfaces. JIRA's web interface and far superior than Team's but Team has solid custom fields.

JIRA supports multi-level and grouping of issues, Team does not.

JIRA requires work for good reports, reports are easy on Team's database. JIRA though has built in dashboards and you can build more.

JIRA allows people to respond to tickets via email and it automatically get add to the ticket as well as add watchers.

JIRA can be built upon with free and commercial add-ons as well as extended integration with other products. Alexsys can be extended, but has some catches and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Deskun](https://deskun.com).

That's a simple ticketing software inside Gmail. You can set and edit an autoreply for customers. The search and filters for tickets are available, you can also see the full history of actions on each ticket. There are different ticket statuses. 
You can also set a deadline on each ticket, assign it to a specific person, reassign it, and leave internal notes.